# My AIR app is showing Allow Application to Check for Updates everytime it's open?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flex4

My AIR app is showing Allow Application to Check for Updates everytime it's opened? I'm using the ApplicationUpdater and ApplicationUpdaterUI classes and calling:

```
updaterUI.initialize();
```

at startup and then on UpdateEvent.INITIALIZED I call:

```
updaterUI.checkNow();
```

Is this correct?

Here is the screen I see:

[image]

BTW I click the "Check for Updates" button and it then says, "No updates available". I would think that on the next time it opens it would check in the background and only pop up a window when an update is available. This is how it seems to work on other AIR apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ApplicationUpdaterUI set the `isCheckForUpdateVisible` property to `false` [refer here for more on ApplicationUpdaterUI](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AIR/1.5/devappsflex/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7ff2.html).*(NOTE: A value set using this property overrides the setting in the update configuration file)*. This will stops the "**Check for Update**" window from displaying and only shows the update window when there is any update available. If you are using configuration file for UpdaterUI then set like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
         <configuration xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/framework/update/configuration/1.0" >
           <url>app:/server/update.xml</url>
           <delay>1</delay>
           <defaultUI>
               <dialog name="checkForUpdate" visible="false" />
               <!-- Other Configs -->
               <dialog name="downloadUpdate" visible="true" />
               <dialog name="downloadProgress" visible="true" />
               <dialog name="installUpdate" visible="true" />    
           </defaultUI>
        </configuration>
```

I hope this will helps you....

Answer (score 0):

When you download the nativeApplicationUpdater framework, it contains two folder: **nativeApplicationUpdater** and **nativeApplicationUpdaterDemo**. Go dig into the nativeApplicationUpdaterDemo folder to understanding how to use the framework.

In my case, I don't use the default Updater UI, just the core nativeApplicationUpdater to check when the update is available (via XML file). If available, download it through APIs and store it into applicationStorageDirectory. At the next time your application launch, you can prompt the user to update, or install it silently and just show the progress bar.

You shouldn't check for update every times your app start, because an user can close and re-open your application many times (Your server will go die). You can log the last time you've check for update to Application Preference, and if (thisTime - lastTimeCheck) > inactivityDuration, then check for update. (I recommend 3 days or a week).

You can search more to learn how to install your application silently, as well as install the Adobe Air run-time silently. Simply un-zip the installer, and install the .msi via command line.

Comment: There's a property called "delay" that is supposed to delay checking for updates in increments of days. If I set delay to 1 it is supposed to only check once a day. However, it is showing me the message every time I launch the application.